# How can I make a formula ignore a blank cell in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

I am creating a budget template and have a formula that multiplies cells. However, not every cell will have a number in it. How do I make it so the formula will ignore blank cells or make them = 1 instead of = 0?

(Example: formula is `=B1*B2*B3`. In some rows, `B3` is empty, in other it has a value. In other rows, `B2` is empty, but `B1` and `B3` have values. How do I create a formula that ignores or counts empty cells as `1` to make the formula work across the board?)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the `Ifs` statement

```
=IFS(B1="",1*B2*B3; B2="", B1*1*B3; B3="", B1*B2*1)
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score -1):

Given you are multiplying another solution would be to replace the empty cells with 1, provided that wouldn't impact in other aspects